# Extracting rows from a table

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to extract rows with their corresponding cells from the following table:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpading="3" width="100%">
<tr bgcolor="#505050">
    <td><b></b></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="white"><b>Last Day</b></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="white"><b>Last Week</b></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#505050">
    <td class="white"><b>Race</b></td>
    <td align="center" class="white"><b>Killed Players</b></td>
    <td align="center" class="white"><b>Killed by Players</b></td>
    <td align="center" class="white"><b>Killed Players</b></td>
    <td align="center" class="white"><b>Killed by Players</b></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1E0C6">
    <td>A</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">3</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">13</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D4C0A1">
    <td>B</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1E0C6">
    <td>C</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D4C0A1">
    <td>D</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#505050">
    <td class=white><b>Total</b></td>
    <td align="right" class="white"><b>210</b></td>
    <td align="right" class="white"><b>1060458</b></td>
    <td align="right" class="white"><b>1132</b></td>
    <td align="right" class="white"><b>5585115</b></td>
</tr>
```

The rows I'm interested in are the ones with A, B, C, and so on with numbers next to them.

The solution I came up with is:

```
table = tree.xpath("//table/tr[td[not(contains(@class, 'white'))]]")

for tr in table:
    print( tr.xpath('td/text()'))
```

However, the output still includes the first row with the empty cell and Last Day/Week ones, and looks like this:

```
['', 'Last Day', 'Last Week']
['A', '0', '3', '0', '13']
['B', '0', '0', '2', '0']
['C', '0', '3', '0', '5']
```

What can be done to get rid of it?

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Comment: Sure, updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just change `tr` to be:**

```
tr[not(contains(@bgcolor, "505050"))]
```

**So your code should look like this:**

```
from lxml import html

HTML = """<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpading="3" width="100%">
<tr bgcolor="#505050">
    <td><b></b></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="white"><b>Last Day</b></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="white"><b>Last Week</b></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#505050">
    <td class="white"><b>Race</b></td>
    <td align="center" class="white"><b>Killed Players</b></td>
    <td align="center" class="white"><b>Killed by Players</b></td>
    <td align="center" class="white"><b>Killed Players</b></td>
    <td align="center" class="white"><b>Killed by Players</b></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1E0C6">
    <td>A</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">3</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">13</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D4C0A1">
    <td>B</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#F1E0C6">
    <td>C</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">1</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#D4C0A1">
    <td>D</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">0</td>
    <td align="right">7</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#505050">
    <td class=white><b>Total</b></td>
    <td align="right" class="white"><b>210</b></td>
    <td align="right" class="white"><b>1060458</b></td>
    <td align="right" class="white"><b>1132</b></td>
    <td align="right" class="white"><b>5585115</b></td>
</tr>"""

tree = html.fromstring(HTML)
results = defaultdict

for item in tree.xpath('//table/tr[not(contains(@bgcolor, "505050"))]'):
    print item.xpath('.//td/text()')
```

**And the output:**

```
['A', '0', '3', '0', '13']
['B', '0', '0', '0', '7']
['C', '0', '0', '0', '1']
['D', '0', '0', '0', '7']
```

---

Still, I would recommend to use a **`dict()`**. See:

```
tree = html.fromstring(HTML)
results = dict()

def unpack(data):
    return data[0], data[1:]

for item in tree.xpath('//table/tr[not(contains(@bgcolor, "505050"))]'):
    key, values = unpack(item.xpath('.//td/text()'))
    results[key] = values

print results
```

Output:

```
{
    'A': ['0', '3', '0', '13'],
    'C': ['0', '0', '0', '1'],
    'B': ['0', '0', '0', '7'],
    'D': ['0', '0', '0', '7']
}
```

> In Python 3, there is not need to have a `unpack()` function like the above one,  you would just need to change
>    `key, values = unpack(item.xpath('.//td/text()'))` to `key, *values = item.xpath('.//td/text()')`

See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

---

Also, if you want, you can sort results by letter (key) using **`sorted()`**:

```
[
  ('A', ['0', '3', '0', '13']),
  ('B', ['0', '0', '0', '7']),
  ('C', ['0', '0', '0', '1']),
  ('D', ['0', '0', '0', '7'])
]
```

Comment: @adrift my pleasure. Please don't forget accepting my answer if it helped you solve the problem :)